# Что такое торпеда у автомобиля?

Tags: выбор-слов, точное-словоупотребление

> Он собирал цветы и травы в ожидании нас. И составлял, кстати, вполне
>   сносные букеты. Он теребил их в руках до следующей остановки, а потом
>   **бросал на торпеду машины**. Было даже жаль, что полевые цветы так быстро гибнут **на ветровом стекле** под палящим солнцем.

Из текста получается (или нет?), что торпеда = ветровое стекло.

Гуглила честно:

> Покраска торпеды автомобиля может быть частью процесса восстановления
>   салона или же являться мероприятием по тюнингу интерьера машины. В
>   первом случае стоит задача максимально приблизиться к заводскому
>   состоянию материалов. Во втором же – наоборот, отдалиться от
>   стандартов и сделать элементы как можно более индивидуальными. Стоит
>   отметить, что **торпеда – эта та часть салона, которая постоянно
>   находится перед глазами. Поэтому, потертости и царапины могут
>   постоянно бросаться в глаза педантичному водителю**. Имейте это в виду
>   и при выборе цвета, желая создать уникальный интерьер.

Comment: Видимо, какой-то жаргонизм, раз и я не понимаю (я не автомобилист по убеждению), сначала даже подумал на газовый баллон у грузовика. Не всякий читатель без сноски поймёт.

Comment: Ога. Автор именно автомобилист, в ралли участвовал. Но что делать с цветами, брошенными внутри салона и гибнущими на ветровом стекле? Караул, однако.

Comment: Как-нибудь "под солнцем, палящим сквозь ветровое стекло"?

Answer (score 1):

Торпедо — название приборной панели автомобиля, ставшее нарицательным по названию компании-производителя «Torpedo»

Comment: Тепло. Но в данном случае речь, очевидно, о [кузове](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), а не о приборной панели. Хотя и то и другое лучше не склонять.

Comment: Тут вариантов быть не может. "на ветровом стекле под палящим солнцем."  Тут речь не о кузове.

Comment: :) Всё проще. Автор всего лишь уподобил машину торпеде. Вроде как "мы стояли на обочине, а мимо с рёвом проносились стальные торпеды машин" :))

Comment: @grizzly :) Всё проще. Автор всего лишь уподобил машину торпеде. Вроде как "мы стояли на обочине, а мимо с рёвом проносились стальные торпеды машин" :))

Comment: @tum "До следующей остановки", значит, машина двигалась. "Он собирал цветы и травы в ожидании нас." - Похоже, что все они переодически двигались, а он их ждал во время остановок. "На ветровом стекле под палящим солнцем" дополняет эту мысль. Без остального контекста не очень четко, но, похоже, что "на ветровом стекле" - это не *на*, а *под* имеется в виду, т.к. при движении машины этого никак не может быть.

Comment: Артём, спасибо, но делать-то что? Ке фер? Фер-то ке?

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova А про "внутри салона" там нету... Кто такой "он" и кто такие "мы" в этом шедевре? "Мы" вроде как ехали на торпеде-машине и делали остановки, а "он" каким-то образом "нас" там поджидал и бросал на эту торпедную машину букеты? Если остановка была долгой, то цветы вполне себе вяли на ветровом стекле. При старте их, надо думать, сдувало... Фуф.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova "Он", наверное, ехал быстрее всех, и на остановке (checkpoint) успевал собрать цветы и травы, пока медленные "мы" до этой же остановки добирались.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova То есть это гонки, а гоночные машины похожи формой на торпеды. (Автор - не Ремарк случайно? У того есть что-то подобное.. :)